# Port 22 is not responding

Tags: ssh, vps, port

I'm trying to make the jump to VPS from shared hosting for better performances and greater flexibility, but am stuck with the fact that I can't access the machine via `ssh`.

First of all, the machine is a CentOS 6.3 cPanel x64 with WHM 11.38.0. Sshd is running (it appears in the current running processes).

Making a port scan I see that port 22 is not responding. Port 21 is, but I am not able to access the machine via `ftp` (I think it's a security measure, but I don't know where to disable/enable it).

So, I'm stuck in WHM and have no way to access the configuration of the machine, neither via `ssh` nor with ftp/sftp.

When trying to connect with `ssh` via Terminal I only get this:

> ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out

I also tried to access with the hostname instead of the IP address and it's the same.

There seem to be no firewall in WHM and I have whitelisted my home IP address to access `ssh`, though there were no restrictions in the first place.

I have been wandering through all the settings and options in WHM for several hours now, but can't seem to find anything.

Does anybody have a clue as to where I should start investigating?

**Update:**
Thanks everyone. It was in fact a matter of firewall. There was a firewall not controlled by the WHM software. I managed to crack into the console from the vps control panel (a terrible, terrible java app that barely took my keyboard input) and disabled the firewall altogether running `service iptables stop` so that I was able to access the console via ssh with the terminal.

Now I will have to set up the firewall again because the command I ran looks like having completely wiped the iptables. Can you recommend any newby-friendly resource where I can learn how to go about this and what should I block? Or should I just go with something like this: http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html ?

Thanks again to everyone who helped me out.

Comment: Get rid of this CPanel crap and start learning to administer the server the real way. This crap will always be in your way and prevent you from learning.

Comment: can you access localy? with ssh user@localhost ?

Comment: @Brigo Thanks for your answer. I don't know any way to do this. The server is remote and I can't login into ssh because port 22 doesn't respond. I can't even access via ftp, so I am pretty much stuck.

Comment: @SvW I am trying to learn to administer the server the way I can, one step at a time. As you can see, I am not even able to connect via ssh. Thanks for taking the time to answer, but you didn't provide constructive help.

Comment: "Operation timed out" pretty much means that your packets aren't reaching the remote host, or the remote host's packets aren't reaching you. If you can reach the remote host on port 21 but not 22, then it's probably a firewall of some kind.

Comment: If you aren't reselling hosting, then cPanel/WHM are just going to get in your way, and their nonstandard way of doing things will make it difficult for you to get help from anyone but cPanel themselves (and sometimes not even from them). Getting rid of it really is the best thing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

First off check that sshd is running

```
service sshd status 
openssh-daemon (pid  9535) is running...
```

or possibly

```
openssh-daemon is stopped
```

in which case you need to [start it](http://linux.die.net/man/8/service).

If it is running check that it's configured to listen on port 22 and your external IP address by looking at [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).

If it is correctly configured to listen on port 22 then look at [your firewall](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) and ensure that it has port 22 open on your external ipaddress.

<sup>Yes I've delibrately left out some details. The reason for this is to allow you to read the documentation yourself and be educated.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't access ssh, so I can't run these commands. Anyway, sshd is running with pid 15754 (I've seen this from the Current Running Processes page in WHM). Is there any other way for me to access the shell?

Comment: If the only problem was that sshd isn't running (or sshd was listening on the wrong port), then the error would be "connection refused" rather than "Operation timed out".

Comment: @Kenster: Starting at the beginning and working out

Comment: I am having this problem still, anyone find a solution?